# Tabbar controller image issues

Tags: ios

[![simulator with tabbar controller][1]][1]

i created tabbar controller and i want to place image inside it but the image got bigger..i did this programmatically without using storyboard..please help me out

```
self.title=@"Speciality";
         NSArray *tabs;
        UIViewController *tab1 = [tabs objectAtIndex:0];
        tab1.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"];
        UIViewController *tab2 = [tabs objectAtIndex:1];
        tab2.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"special.png"];


        self.view =singleView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code :

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
self.tabBarItem.image = [self imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(30, 30)];

- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: I need to set in imageview and then i have to set in tab bar controller...pls tell me that coding